# Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference - IE11 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I am new to **Javascript** and **jQuery** and having trouble in fixing this error.

I get this error when I try to debug in **IE11** and chrome. Initially I got

> Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference

in **jquery.validate.min.js** for `event.handle.call` and I did some research and fixed it by changing to `event.dispatch.call`. As soon as I fixed that I am getting this error and couldn't find any good resolution.

I am using **jQuery 1.10.*** and want to fix this error when debugging **IE11** and **Chrome**.

Any suggestions would be really useful. Point me to any useful resource or a possible fix.

EDIT:

I am getting this error in **function handlerProxy** in jQuery-ui-1.10.3.js

```
$.each( handlers, function( event, handler ) {
    function handlerProxy() {
        // allow widgets to customize the disabled handling
        // - disabled as an array instead of boolean
        // - disabled class as method for disabling individual parts
        if ( !suppressDisabledCheck &&
                ( instance.options.disabled === true ||
                    $( this ).hasClass( "ui-state-disabled" ) ) ) {
            return;
        }
        return ( typeof handler === "string" ? instance[ handler ] : handler )
            .apply( instance, arguments );
    }
}
```

Comment: While developing, using not minified file _jquery.validate.js_ instead of _jquery.validate.min.js_ will help you find the error. Try to use the debugger of your browser. Can't provide more help without code.

Comment: @Volune: Please look at the EDIT, added the function where I am getting the error.

Comment: The JS you posted only create a `handlerProxy` function inside the scope of the `$.each` loop without triggering it. And the each is missing a closing `)`. Also because it is a loop `handler` will always reference the last one so the variable even when present inside `handlerProxy` will always have the value of the last `handler`

Comment: The posted javascript is part of [jquery.ui](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js). There are very few chances your problems comes from inside the library. It probably comes from how you use the library, and that's what you need to show in your question. Also try to break on error and look at the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you were using an outdated version of jquery.validate.  Get the latest version for your version of jquery and it should work.  That's the way that I fixed this problem.  I was using jquery 1.11 and jquery.validate 1.10 and update validate to 1.11 and it worked fine.